# I can't read attribut 'ref' of dom element in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, refs

I can't read attribute `ref` after the form validation. The result is `undefined` and I don't understand why.

```
import React from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';

export default class Home extends React.Component {.

handleSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    console.log(e.name.value);
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <input type='text' ref={ (input) => this.name = input} />
                <input type='text' ref={ (input) => this.topic = input} />
                <input type='submit'/>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

you are storing it in the component itself, the value should be available under

```
console.log(this.name)
```

`e` is the event that gets triggered when you click on the input. In your case, you are using an arrow function, so `this` in the context of the callback is the `Home` component.

EDIT:

You also need to bind `handleSubmit` so that it has access to the right `this`. Add this to the `Home` component:

```
constructor () {
  super()
  this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
}
```

Comment: Thank's for your answer Mario. I tried, but i have this error : "Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"

Comment: @NedjimDN you are right, your `handleSubmit` method does not have access to `this` as it is not bound to the component. I updated my answer with that.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to log `this.name.value` instead of this 
`console.log(e.name.value);`

You also need to include this

```
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
}
```

Comment: Thank's for your answer Adil. I tried, but i have this error : "Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"

Answer (score 0):

The `e` variable is holding an event. You are looking for `e.target` to get the element the event was fired on.

```
console.log(e.target.name.value);
```